# Creating a set of elements from a set of `id`s

Tags: jquery

I want to create a set of elements out from an array of `id`s so that it can be used as a jquery receiver. For example, if I have ids: `id1`, `id2`, `id3`, how can I turn this into a jquery selector so that the corresponding elements appear in this order? Supposing what I want is `theJquerySelector`, I then would like to apply a jquery operation like this:

```
theJquerySelector.appendTo($(...))
```

where `$(...)` is another jquery selector irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `Array`s [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method as such;

```
$('#' + yourArrayOfIds.join(', #')).appendTo($(/* */));
```

A more jQuery-esque way would be to either write a utility function to do this for you on the jQuery object *(and then call it a "plugin")*, or to add classes to the relevant elements and select via that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `^` to select attributes that start with a string.

```
$("[id^=id]").appendTo($(..));
```

To sort them first

```
$($("[id^=id]").toArray().sort(function(a, b) { a.id - b.id } )).appendTo()
```

It seems you have to rewrap the result of sort to get a jQuery object, not sure why.